# How to compare the special characters such as ' (' , '/', ' ' in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a character array, `cA`, and each entry of each stores a single character, such as `'a'`, `'('`, `'['`, and `'  '`. 
My program will iterate this array and perform a certain type of operation based on the content of each entry. For example,

```
if (cA(i) == 'a')  do sth; end
```

For the characters such as `'a'` , `'b'`, the above character comparison operation is trivial.
But how can I handle the special characters such as `'('`,  `'['` and `'  '`( a blank space)
Can I write something such as

```
if (cA(i) == ' ')      
if (cA(i) == '(')
```

Comment: yes you can. Depending on your intended use, you can even vectorize this: for example `idx = (cA == 'a')` will return all indices where the array is equal to the character `a`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, I suggest comparing strings using [STRCMP](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/strcmp.html), e.g.

```
if strcmp(cA(i),'('), doSomething, end
```

For your specific case, I suggest a [SWITCH/CASE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/switch.html) statement. Note that in Matlab, this doesn't fall through like in c; instead, only the "good" case gets executed. In my experience, this helps readability. Thus

```
for myChar = cA %# this loops over every char in the 1-by-n string
   switch myChar
      case 'a'
         do something
      case 'b'
      case {'c','d'} %# this is how you handle multiple chars with the same outcome
      otherwise
         error('char %s not handled',myChar) %# don't forget this
   end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try it and get an error? Because it works for me:

```
c = '(';
if(c == '(') 
  disp('left paren')
end
```

This prints `left paren`, as expected.